# ASP.net Hot to create custom command for control that implement ITemplate interface?

Tags: asp.net, command, dynamic-data, itemplate

I have control that inherited from `ITemplate` Interface.
Data is displayed in `HtmlTable` control,  that automatically generated on control initialization.
Each row contain `ImageButton` controls that represent standard command (Edit, Delete, etc).
Here code for creating `ImageButton` with standard command and adding it to row template:

```
var lkbCancel = new ImageButton()
{
    CommandName = "Edit",
    ImageUrl = "EditIco.png",
    ToolTip = "Edit",
    CausesValidation = false,
};

commandCell.Controls.Add(lkbCancel);
```

I would like to add `ImageButton` with custom command (not standard commands Add, Edit, Delete and other).
So, how to add custom command and handle it correctly in `Itemplate` control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subscribe to the click event ?

```
lkbCancel.Click += (sender,e) => {
    //Do something here..
};
```

You can get access to the current data item that is bound to the row, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0h809ak%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: But I cannot access to underplaying row in Click event implementation... </br> May be is exists some way to pass current row in Click or Command events?

Comment: How do you currently handle the `Edit` and `Delete` commands ?

Comment: You probably could get access to the table row as you are in the control tree using `NamingContainer` or `Parent`, however you can access the data item the row is bound to, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0h809ak(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I don't handle `Edit` and `Delete` commands. This is standard comaands and automatically handled in bindable objects. I just specify "Edit" or "Delete" in `CommandName` property and command will works as expected without any additional actions.